# How to add logger to a maven project with separated ejb, web and ear package?

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

The project is organized in three modules, the ejb that becomes a jar, the web that becomes a war and ear that package the project in an ear file.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <name>ada</name>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>es.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>app-ejb</module>
        <module>app-web</module>
        <module>app-ear</module>
    </modules>
    ...
```

I added the log4j.properties only in app-web module.

**app-web/src/main/resources/log4j.properties**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout 

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{3}](%L): %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: You could define a `Log4jConfigListener` in your web module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548547/difference-between-log4jconfiglistener-and-log4jservletcontextlistener-while-con

Answer (score 0):

By accessing the file system directly (by writing to a log file) you violate the Java EE specification making you subtly vendor dependent.  The servlet logging mechanism does not work well out of the box with slf4j.

Instead switch your logging to slf4j and send to the JDK14 logger which most containers capture and store.  It is then up to the container to provide the log files you need.